# Headless_ie_driver Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.')

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless, headless-browser

I'm trying to run a simple headless web-browser;

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Ie("headless_ie_selenium.exe")
driver.get("www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
```

And I'm getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.') for URL 'http://localhost:65393/'
```

What I've tried but didn't work:

1:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()
caps['ie.ensureCleanSession']= True
driver = webdriver.Ie("headless_ie_selenium.exe",capabilities=caps)
```

2: All Internet Options Security settings are at the same level and all have checked Enabled Protected Mode;

3: Searched for a C:\Program folder to delete, but there was nothing.

**Notes**: The same code works fine with the normal webdriver (IEDriverServer.exe), and when I open the **headless_ie_selenium.exe** manually it starts:

```
Selenium driver found at: path..\IEDriverServer.exe
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.8.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing says it all :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.') for URL 'http://localhost:65393/'
```

If you visit the [`Release Page`](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win/releases) of [**`headless-selenium-for-win`**](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win/releases) the `Release Notes` for [**`headless-selenium-for-win v1.4`**](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win/releases) it clearly mentions the following :

- Supporting Firefox and Chrome
- Windows explorer is not started anymore in the headless desktop.
- desktop_utils.exe learned to not run explorer.exe after a headless desktop is created.

Hence **Internet Explorer** can't be initialized with **headless_ie_selenium.exe**.

---

### Update :

As per your comment `Are there any alternatives to open IE and run it in background via selenium with mouse/keyboard inputs` the straight `Answer` is **No**.

@JimEvans in the Github Thread [**`Headless IE with selenium not working on Windows server`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4551) clearly mentions that :

> **`The IE driver does not support execution without an active, logged-in desktop session running. You'll need to take this up with the author of the solution you're using to achieve "headless" (scare quotes intentional) execution of IE.`**

He also adds :

> **`Mouse and keyboard simulation won't work without an active session. It's a browser limitation, not a driver limitation.`**

Comment: Well, are there any alternatives to open IE and run it in background via selenium with mouse/keyboard inputs?