# Which drivers support "no-browser"/"headless" testing?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, headless, headless-browser

Actually I want to run my selenium code on server where dont want open the any browser. But I am confused which webdriver is use for the server which do all task (where I download some files from some site and store in my server).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Selenium support headless browser testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568899/does-selenium-support-headless-browser-testing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To execute your *Test Suite*  through *Selenium* without opening any browser you can use any of the *Browser Client* from the following list :

- [**Headless Chrome**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) : Here you can find an [*working example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462).
- [**Headless Firefox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode) : Here you can find an [*working example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programatically-in-selenium-with-python/46768243#46768243).
- [**PhantomJS**](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) : Here you can find an [*working example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50025571/how-to-initialize-phantomjs-browser-through-selenium-java/50026794#50026794).
- [**HtmlUnitDriver**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver) : Here you can find an [*working example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273474/unable-to-launch-htmlunitdriver-through-selenium-3-4-0/50274121#50274121).
- [**headless-selenium-for-win**](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win/releases) : Here you can find a detailed [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322719/headless-ie-driver-unexpected-error-launching-internet-explorer-ielaunchurl-r/48325928#48325928).

---

### Headless Browser

[**`Headless Browser`**](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers#headless-browsers) is a web browser without a *Graphical User Interface* controlled programmatically used for automation, testing, and other purposes.

### Headless Browser Engines

These [**`Headless Browser Engines`**](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers#browser-engines) fully render web pages or run JavaScript in a virtual DOM :

[image: Headless Browser Engines]

### Headless Multi Drivers

These [**`Headless Multi Drivers`**](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers#multi-drivers) libraries can control multiple browser engines (typically using Selenium) :

[image: Headless Multi Drivers]

Answer (score 1):

HtmlUnitDriver and  PhantomJSDriver are two webdrivers for headless testing without need of opening browsers.

Comment: PhantomJSDriver  is now deprecated