# Unable to launch HtmlUnitdriver through Selenium 3.4.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, ghostdriver, htmlunit-driver

I am tried to run the HtmlUnitDriver with selenium 3.4 and chrome Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (32-bit).
My code is:

```
package eclipse;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.UnexpectedAlertBehaviour;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;  
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;

public class Unit
{
    WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        WebDriver driver;
        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to Initialize headless browser :

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME ,true);
driver.get("your web URL");
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke **HtmlUnitDriver** with **Selenium v3.4.0** you don't need *ChromeDriver* or *Chrome Browser Client* instead you can use the `org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver` module following the solution below :

- Code Block :

  ```
  package HtmlUnitDriver;

  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

  public class htmlUnitDriver {

      public static void main(String[] args) {


          WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
          System.out.println("Invoking Facebook through HtmlUnitDriver");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  Invoking Facebook through HtmlUnitDriver
  Facebook – log in or sign up
  ```

**Note** : Ensure that `HtmlUnitDriver()` is not resolved from :

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
```

Comment: I am tried with this : But output is - log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Invoking Facebook through HtmlUnitDriver

Comment: can you please tell me the HtmlUnitDriver compatible version ?

Comment: @Naveen This code block will work on **Selenium v3.4.0** and the recent **Selenium v3.12.0**. Simply copy-paste the code and change the _Package Name_

Comment: I am using v3.4.0... i have tried simply copy and paste the code but page title are not coming for me ?

Comment: @Naveen These warning messages **log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.** are coming as you haven't configured `Log4j` module for this project. Else you are getting proper _Console Output_ as follows **Invoking Facebook through HtmlUnitDriver** I think your program is executing just perfect :)

Comment: Version for Log4j ?

Comment: @Naveen Leave out `Log4j` for now. That is a separate module to generate more verbose _Log Messages_. Your program is working fine.

Comment: If reinstalled the log4j its enough ? otherwise how I will get output ?

Comment: @Naveen Cool down man, take a deep breathe, your program is working fine. You are getting expected output in the console as **Invoking Facebook through HtmlUnitDriver**

Comment: The other _log messages_ are `WARN` messages and you can ignore them for the time being.