# Sending selenium chrome instance to the background using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, google-chrome-headless, pyvirtualdisplay

I am trying to open a simple chrome instance using Python and selenium.
Please find my code below:

```
import time, datetime, sys, os
start_time = time.time()
from datetime import datetime
os.system("cls")
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

CHROME_PATH = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\'+userID+'\\'+filename+'\\chromedriver.exe'
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"

chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,chrome_options=chrome_options)
time.sleep(1)
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
os.system("cls")
time.sleep(2)
```

I would like this to open in the background ie when I am typing something else the mouse/cursor focus should not randomly go to this automated chrome instance once it opens.

Limitations: Please note the below limitations:

1. I can not use "--headless"
2. I can not use phantomJS
3. I can not use PyVirtualDisplay as the code(exe file) will eventually be deployed on windows machines for the end-users.

Would there be any other way to push this chrome instance to the background?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is **no** programatic way to open in the ***Browser Client*** at the background or as a ***Background Process***.

Of coarse the alternative way is to use a **Headless Browser** and you can find a detailed discussion in [Which drivers support “no-browser”/“headless” testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368002/which-drivers-support-no-browser-headless-testing).

### Why not possible?

Software Test Automation is an art. Your *Test Framework* should be:

- Configured with all the required *softwares*, *libraries* and *binaries*.
- *Test Execution* must be performed in a controled environment for optimized performance.
- While your `@Tests` are executing, it should be free from *Manual Intervention*.
- Particularly when your `@Tests` are *Selenium* based, while *test execution* is *InProgress* the *Test Environment* shouldn't be intervened because of the following reasons:

  - At the lowest level, the behavior of `actions` *class* is intended to mimic the remote end's behavior with an actual input device as closely as possible, and the implementation strategy may involve e.g. injecting synthesized events into a browser event loop. Therefore the steps to dispatch an action will inevitably end up in implementation-specific territory. However there are certain content observable effects that must be consistent across implementations. To accommodate this, the specification requires that remote ends perform implementation-specific action dispatch steps, along with a list of events and their properties. This list is not comprehensive; in particular the default action of the input source may cause additional events to be generated depending on the implementation and the state of the browser (e.g. input events relating to key actions when the focus is on an editable element, scroll events, etc.).
- Moreover,

  - An activation trigger generated by the WebDriver API user needs to be indistinguishable from those generated by a real user interacting with the browser. In particular, the dispatched events will have the isTrusted attribute set to true. The most robust way to dispatch these events is by creating them in the browser implementation itself. Sending OS-specific input messages to the browser's window has the disadvantage that the browser being automated may not be properly isolated from a user accidentally modifying input source state. Use of an OS-level accessibility API has the disadvantage that the browser's window must be focused, and as a result, multiple WebDriver instances cannot run in parallel.
  - An advantage of an OS-level accessibility API is that it guarantees that inputs correctly mirror user input, and allows interaction with the host OS if necessary. This might, however, have performance penalties from a machine utilisation perspective.
- Additionally,

  - [**Robot Class**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) is used to generate native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed. The primary purpose of Robot is to facilitate automated testing of Java platform implementations. Using the class to generate input events differs from posting events to the AWT event queue or AWT components in that the events are generated in the platform's native input queue. For example, Robot.mouseMove will actually move the mouse cursor instead of just generating mouse move events.
- Finally, as per [Internet Explorer and Native Events](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#native-events-and-internet-explorer):

  - As the InternetExplorerDriver is Windows-only, it attempts to use so-called "native", or OS-level events to perform mouse and keyboard operations in the browser. This is in contrast to using simulated JavaScript events for the same operations. The advantage of using native events is that it does not rely on the JavaScript sandbox, and it ensures proper JavaScript event propagation within the browser. However, there are currently some issues with mouse events when the IE browser window does not have focus, and when attempting to hover over elements.
- Browser Focus:

  - The challenge is that IE itself appears to not fully respect the Windows messages we send the IE browser window (WM_MOUSEDOWN and WM_MOUSEUP) if the window doesn't have the focus. Specifically, the element being clicked on will receive a focus window around it, but the click will not be processed by the element. Arguably, we shouldn't be sending messages at all; rather, we should be using the SendInput() API, but that API explicitly requires the window to have the focus. We have two conflicting goals with the WebDriver project.
  - First, we strive to emulate the user as closely as possible. This means using native events rather than simulating the events using JavaScript.
  - Second, we want to not require focus of the browser window being automated. This means that just forcing the browser window to the foreground is suboptimal.

### Conclusion

Always keep the **Test Environment** seperate from **Development Environment** and absolutely free from *Manual Intervention*.

Comment: Thank you and apologies if I was misleading. What I meant by "sending the chrome instance to the background" was "to ensure that the cursor focus does not randomly go to that chrome instance in the middle of my other work". Also you mention that for testing it would be ideal to allow the user to interact with the chrome instance. However, could you then suggest what one can use in case it is not a "testing scenario" but more a case when a list of tasks need to be completed in the background?

Comment: @Stan As I mentioned in my answer, _Selenium_ needs **focus** specifically when you are dealing with _Actions_ class. Again _to allow the user to interact with the chrome instance_ is a big **No**. Finally, if at all it is a **background** task, _Selenium_ may not be the _best fit_ solution for you. Let me know if this answers all your queries.

Answer (score 2):

On windows you could use "task scheduler", if you set open while login or while staring the system it would open in background.
In selenium i found only:

```
browser.set_window_position(-10000, 0)
browser.set_window_size(0, 0) # this is optional
```

but browser will be visible on the taskbar(you cannot open it).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS9uA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I ask same question to chatgpt and below code is working for me

```
    import threading
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

def send_whatsapp_message():
    # Path to your Chrome WebDriver executable
    chrome_driver_path = "path_to_your_chromedriver.exe"

    # Create Chrome options
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    # Create Chrome WebDriver instance
    service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

    # Open WhatsApp Web
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")

    # Wait for user to scan QR code and log in manually
    input("Scan the QR code and then press Enter to continue...")

    # Find the chat input field
    chat_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@contenteditable="true"][@data-tab="6"]')

    # Enter the contact name or group name you want to send message to
    contact_name = "Contact Name or Group Name"

    # Find the contact/group by searching
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@contenteditable="true"][@data-tab="3"]')
    search_box.send_keys(contact_name)

    # Wait for search results to load
    time.sleep(2)

    # Click on the contact/group
    contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//span[@title="{contact_name}"]')
    contact.click()

    # Find the message input field
    message_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@contenteditable="true"][@data-tab="1"]')

    # Enter the message you want to send
    message = "Your message here"

    # Type and send the message
    message_input.send_keys(message)
    message_input.send_keys(webdriver.common.keys.Keys.RETURN)

    # Close the WebDriver session
    driver.quit()

# Start a new thread for WebDriver
whatsapp_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_whatsapp_message)
whatsapp_thread.start()

# Continue with the main thread
print("Main thread continues to execute...")
# You can continue with other tasks here

# Wait for the WebDriver thread to finish
whatsapp_thread.join()

# All tasks completed
print("All tasks completed.")
```