# Chromedriver stops running when in background using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to scrape data from a website.
Everything works fine, however, I experience that if I switch to another tab to work on something else, chromedriver stops finding the elements on the page without throwing an error. It goes into exception right away.

Once I go to chrome, it starts processing again. 
I am using Max OS High Sierra 10.13.16.

Using windows, I did not have this problem.
Is there a way that it can literally run in the background, meaning if the browser is not visible?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730392/python-sending-selenium-chrome-instance-to-the-background/52741949#52741949) helps you?

Comment: Use --headless mode

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you found a solution?